# How to sum the values of a column based on the result of another SELECT query?

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables:
posts:

```
id   post
1   'p1'
2   'p2'
3   'p3'
```

comments:

```
id   comment post_id
1   'c1'     1
2   'c2'     1
3   'c3'     2
```

comments_likes:

```
id   comment_id   like
1    1            1
2    1            1
3    2           -1
```

I would like to run a query for a specific post (e.g. `post_id = 1` and get the following:

```
comment_id   comment   likes   
1            'c1'       2
2            'c2'      -1
3            'c3'       0
```

I have tried a couple of queries with no luck:
e.g.:

```
SELECT comment_id, SUM(like) AS likes
FROM comments_likes cl
RIGHT JOIN (
SELECT * 
FROM comments
WHERE post_id=1
) c ON c.id = cl.comment_id;
```

or

```
SELECT c.*, cl.likes 
FROM comments c 
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT comment_id, SUM(like) AS likes 
   FROM comments_likes
   ) cl ON cl.comment_id = c.id 
WHERE c.post_id = 1;
```

Does anyone have any idea how to do it in a single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try using a sum

```
select id, comment, sum( ifnull(like,0) likes  
from  comments 
left  join  comments_likes on a.id = comments_likes.comment_id 
where  post_id =1
group by  id, comment
```

or for all post

```
select post.post,  comments.id, comments.comment, sum( ifnull(commnents_like,0) likes  
from  post
inner join  comments on post.id = comment.post_id 
left  join  comments_likes on a.id = comments_likes.comment_id 

group by   post.post,  comments.id, comments.comment
```

Comment: it worked like a charm :D. Could you explain please how the ``` sum( ifnull(like,0) ``` work?

Comment: due the presence of left  join you obtain null value for row that don't  match (that don't have likes)  .. for these rows  you trasform the null value in 0 and the you can sum properly all the values ..also wher there is no values

Answer (score 0):

```
ifnull(commnents_like,0)
```

IFNULL() : function lets you return an alternative value if an expression is NULL: